# react-native-community/react-native-datetimepicker not allowing me to set a date

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm somewhat new to react native development and I'm trying to make a basic Alarm Clock application, but I've been running into an issue with react-native-community/react-native-datetimepicker for the past couple days and I'm fresh out of ideas to try.

The issue being that using the time picker just doesn't seem to allow me to set a time for some reason. To elaborate, whenever I tap a time on the android time picker (as I've only been able to test it on Android), within a few moments it changes back to the original time value, as if being reset (i.e. when on the "hours" stage, if it is set to 12 and I press 5, it will display 5 on click but change back to 12 less than 3 seconds afterwards).

Here is the basic code snippet minus non-essentials:

```html
state = {
title: this.props.title,
date: new Date(),
show: false
}
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.handleDateTimeChange = this.handleDateTimeChange.bind(this);
}

render() {
    return (
        <DateTimePicker
            mode={'time'}
            display={'default'}
            value={this.state.date}
            onChange={this.handleDateTimeChange}
        />
    )
}
handleDateTimeChange(event, date){
    if(event.type == 'dismissed'){
        this.setState({
            show: false
        })
    } else {
        this.setState({
            date,
            show:false
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: can make an [snack](https://snack.expo.io)?

Comment: got any solution?